# Variable passed to Javascript returns NULL when added to Input Value

Tags: javascript

So, basically I am trying to pass a variable to a piece of javascript code and then in turn set this value as a hidden input value.

```
<img alt="" src="Image.jpg" style="width:50px" class="thisclass" title="Title" onclick="thisfunction('Text Here')" />
```

The value clearly passes okay as I am able to process it with a switch command successfully.

```
function thisfunction(thisvariable) {
    switch(thisvariable) {
        case 'Text Here' :
```

However, when I try to set the value of a hidden

```
<input type="hidden" name="ThisInput" value="N/A" />

document.getElementById("ThisInput").value = thisvariable;
```

I get the following error in the javascript console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
```

I have also tried

```
$('#ThisInput').val(thisvariable);
```

However this just seems to blank the value.

Comment: I don't see id attribute...

Answer (score 3):

Looking at this part of your code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ThisInput" value="N/A" />
document.getElementById("ThisInput").value = thisvariable;
```

`document.getElementByID` and `$("#...")` will find the ID of an element. "ThisInput" is the **name** - it has no ID set.

This would work:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ThisInput" value="N/A" />
document.getElementById("ThisInput").value = thisvariable;
```

Or if you want to keep it as a `name` attribute, use a jQuery attribute selector:

```
$("input[name='ThisInput']").val(thisvariable);
```

Comment: Sometimes you stare at something long enough and your brain just turns to mush.  Thanks for this, but having added in the id as above the code is now blanking the value as per the jquery attempt.

Comment: Before the jQuery attempt, try putting `console.log(thisvariable)`. What outputs to the console? It could be that `thisvariable` is in fact blank - try it with a constant, like `$(....).val("Test");` and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

you try to select the HTML element via ID.

```
<input type="hidden" id="ThisInput" name="ThisInput" value="N/A" />
```

use this and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ThisInput" id="ThisInput" value="N/A" />

<script>
  $('#ThisInput').attr('value',thisvariable);
</script>
```

Comment: Try place an id in your input tag:

<input type="hidden" name="ThisInput" id="ThisInput" value="N/A" />

Comment: Thank You duellsy . Had forgotten the tags <script></script>